# How To assign Values to Interface Variables with Interface Datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, interface

Can any body help me in implementing the below interface, Your prompt response would be appreciated.

```
public interface IApple
{
IApple Brand { get; }
string Name { get; }
}
```

This is what i tried to implement

```
public class AppleChild :IApple 
{

      private string _name;
      private string _brand;
      public AppleChild()
 {
    _brand = "sad";
    _name = "adsa";


   }
  IApple IApple.Brand => _brand; --getting error here it says Cannot convert type string 
to IApple
  string IApple.Name {
   get
   {
       return _name;
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely this:

```cs
IApple Brand { get; }
```

should be this:

```cs
string Brand { get; }
```

Comment: But i have been asked to implement the interface as it is. That means something else need to be done here.

Comment: @Bilal, if that property is supposed to be type IApple then why are you using a string field? That fact shows that you think it should be a string too. If it's not then don't use a string field in your class. The obvious solution is to use the correct type. As it is though, any type implementing that interface is going to be recursive as you can never have an object that doesn't refer to another object of that type. The interface simply doesn't make sense as it is.